# Programmatically create machine startup script in local Group Policy: script executes but is not visible in Group Policy Editor

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, group-policy, powershell-5.0

I have managed to programmatically create machine startup Powershell script for Windows 10 Pro and place it in the local Group Policy (see below a powershell script used for creation of startup script).  
 Just to reiterate: *I am using local Group Policy and my computer is not in a Domain.*

Startup script logs its execution in the Event Log and everything goes perfectly as I see appropriate events in the log.

### Problem

When I open local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`) and look into Computer startup scripts there are no any scripts registered as you can see from the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of Group Policy Editor]

The script itself is correctly placed in the directory for Group Policy scripts (`C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup`)

---

### Powershell script used for creation of the machine startup script in local Group Policy

```
$path = "$ENV:systemRoot\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup"
if (-not (Test-Path $path)) {
    New-Item -path $path -itemType Directory
}
'Write-EventLog -LogName xxx -source Scripts -EntryType Information -EventId 2 -Message "Execute machine startup script: $psCommandPath"' | 
    Out-File -filePath "$path\AllUsersStartup.ps1" -encoding ascii

# Add script to Group Policy through the Registry
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Startup\0\0',
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Startup\0\0' |
  ForEach-Object { 
    if (-not (Test-Path $_)) {
        New-Item -path $_ -force
    }
  }

'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Startup\0',
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Startup\0' |
  ForEach-Object {
    New-ItemProperty -path "$_" -name DisplayName -propertyType String -value "Local Group Policy" 
    New-ItemProperty -path "$_" -name FileSysPath -propertyType String -value "$ENV:systemRoot\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine" 
    New-ItemProperty -path "$_" -name GPO-ID -propertyType String -value "LocalGPO"
    New-ItemProperty -path "$_" -name GPOName -propertyType String -value "Local Group Policy"
    New-ItemProperty -path "$_" -name PSScriptOrder -propertyType DWord -value 2 
    New-ItemProperty -path "$_" -name SOM-ID -propertyType String -value "Local"
  }
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Startup\0\0',
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Startup\0\0' |
  ForEach-Object {
    New-ItemProperty -path "$_" -name Script -propertyType String -value 'AllUsersStartup.ps1'
    New-ItemProperty -path "$_" -name Parameters -propertyType String -value ''
    New-ItemProperty -path "$_" -name IsPowershell -propertyType DWord -value 1
    New-ItemProperty -path "$_" -name ExecTime -propertyType QWord -value 0
  }
```

Comment: Check `scripts.ini` and `psscripts.ini` in `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts` rather than registry.

Comment: @JosefZ thanks, I had no clue about psScripts.ini. After googling found good explanation http://www.hexacorn.com/blog/2017/01/07/beyond-good-ol-run-key-part-52 how to deal with this file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that local Group Policy Editor gets the list and order of scripts not only from the Registry but also from `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\psScripts.ini`.  This is almost usual .ini file with some weird features: it should be in UTF-16LE BOM format and can be with both `CR`+`LF` and `LF` line endings (which is rather strange for Windows).

Below you'll find a piece of code to write correct `psScripts.ini` for adding machine startup script to local Group Policy.

> Code requires [PsIni](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni) module which can be installed by `Install-Module -Name PsIni`

```
#Requires -Module psIni

$scriptsConfig = @{
    StartExecutePSFirst = 'true'
    EndExecutePSFirst =   'true'
}
$startup = @{
    '0CmdLine' =    'AllUsersStartup.ps1'
    '0Parameters' = ''
}
$newIniContent = [ordered] @{ 
    ScriptsConfig = $scriptsConfig
    Startup =       $startup 
}
$newIniContent | Out-IniFile -filePath C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\psScripts.ini -encoding Unicode -force
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment on `maoizm`s post, but you can prefix his script with the following to completely automate the process:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Install-Module -Name PsIni

...
```